# IE Conditionals on html 5 boilerplate or initializr don't work with Modernizr?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, modernizr, html5boilerplate

The way IE Conditionals work on HTML5Boilerplate / initializr doesn't seem to work with Modernizr.

What I mean is that the `<html>` element doesn't contain the correct class for ie, if for example `lt-ie9`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

On IE < 9 for example, I get:

```
<html class=" js no-flexbox no-canvas...">
```

So, as you can tell, there's no way I can target ie<9 by using the lt-ie9 class.

I've been noticing this for quite a while and I usually end up having to use javascript to add the class dynamically.

So, I'd like to know if this is correct.  Anyone else experienced this?

**I'm using IE10 Dev tool, on IE8 mode, so not sure if conditionals are supported**

Thanks for looking!

Comment: I tried on my local IE (Windows 7, IE 10, with Dev toolbar changing both browser and document mode) - http://jsbin.com/qugozoki/1 but conditional comments work just fine! can you post jsfiddle / HTML markup / URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Conditional comments are not support in IE 10](http://www.sitepoint.com/microsoft-drop-ie10-conditional-comments/).

Use the actual browser - you can download free virtual machines from [modern.ie](http://modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads)